# Can you build a house on a colour group property while another property of that colour group is mortgaged?

Tags: monopoly

Say I have mortgaged Old Kent Road, can I still build a house on Whitechapel Road? Or would I need to unmortgage Old Kent before building a house on Whitechapel? Both of these properties are in the brown property group

Comment: Something to note for the future it would be good to include that they are in the same property group as not everyone would know that.

Comment: British Monopoly?

Comment: I've edited the title, as the original was unclear as to whether it was "(another colour group) property" or "another (colour group property)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you are unable to build houses on any property in a color group where any property is mortgaged. While it does not mention it in the rules about houses it does mention that all hotels and houses must be sold prior to mortgaging any property of that color group. The rules also follow up with an explicit statement that you may begin to buy houses back once all properties in that group are no longer mortgaged.

[Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf)

> MORTGAGES… Unimproved properties can be mortgaged through
> the Bank at any time. Before an improved property can be mortgaged,
> all the buildings on all the properties of its color-group must be sold
> back to the Bank at half price. The mortgage value is printed on each
> Title Deed card

> When all the properties of a
> color-group are no longer mortgaged, the owner may begin to buy
> back houses at full price.

Comment: At the end of the "Mortgages" section in the rules you've linked, it explicitly says _"When all the properties of a color-group are no longer mortgaged, the owner may begin to buy back houses at full price."_

Comment: @PlayerOne Thank you for that information, I looked at the rules but I must have missed it. I have modified my answer to include that.